# Ionic2 cordova-plugin-advanced-http not working

Tags: cordova, http, plugins, ionic2

I was trying to implement HTTP in ionic2 using the link  [Ionic HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)
and followed the steps.but it throws an error in Xcode as shown bellow and the http request was failed.

> WARN: Native: tried calling HTTP.get, but the HTTP plugin is not
>   installed.
>   WARN: Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add
>   cordova-plugin-advanced-http'

but the plugin is already installed.here is the list of plugins installed

```
>ionic cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.5.9 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0 "PushPlugin"
```

Comment: is it present in your config.xml?

Comment: I changed cordova-plugin-http  to do ajax request in my app to resolve this issue